# Any simple way to edit an existing pdf/png image on android?

Tags: android, pdf

I want to edit an existing pdf/png image on android studio and having hard time.
I have a pdf/png file which I want to edit some areas in it, save it and share it as a png/pdf.
I've searched for different libraries for pdf but most of them have an expensive license which I can't afford.
Is there any other way to edit and share the file?

Comment: What is a pdf/png or a png/pdf?

Comment: @greenapps i meant pdf or png

Comment: Why do you name them together? Handling them is quite different.